# Summarizing duplicate data without losses

Tags: excel, google-sheets

I have a file with annualized data about businesses in my area, it is formatted in the way, that for each year, there is a seperate 'sheet' with all the businesses which were active that year.
Now I want to create a 'master sheet' of all the data.
Each business is represented by the following data:

| id | latitude | longitude | year |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 15214537 | 14.4248605 | 50.0786082 | 2017 |

I want to somehow import all the data from all seven sub-sheets onto the master sheet, whilst checking for duplicates via the id data point and if one is found I want to be able to tell which sub-sheets they are from. Maybe if it could check the year and then output true/false in an according column?

| id | latitude | longitude | 2017 | 2018 | 2019 | 2020 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 15214537 | 14.4248605 | 50.0786082 | true | true | false | true |

This is the first 'real' programming problem I have ever tried to solve with excel/sheets so I have no idea where to start. Should I first import all the data onto the master sheet and then sort? How do I even sort it?
Should I do this in Excel, Google Sheets, or would R be better?

Thanks for any help

Due to my limited programming knowledge I have tried to solve it via Asking ChatGPT which helped me figure most things out before, but now I don't know where to even begin.

Comment: You need to know, or decide, which you are using\; Excel or Googlesheets as some functions behave differently.

Comment: Hi Cihla Face!  Welcome to StackOverflow! Congratulations on starting your first 'real' programming problem (the hardest part is starting)

Comment: in the second sheet, are the year columns checking if there are duplicates in the sheet? i.e. if there's no duplicate, it is TRUE?

Comment: Re:Should I first import all the data onto the master sheet and then sort? The question is, is there any value to you in having them separate (e.g. do you want to look at specific years a lot? If yes, then don't separate, if no, then separate

Comment: Re:Excel/Google Sheets/R - I am biased so I think R is the best, but probably whatever you feel most comfortable with is best

Comment: I am currently using Google sheets, but i can also switch to excel if that would be easier, tahts why i included both.

Comment: @CihlaFace if you have a list of all of the IDs across every year already, you could do a xlookup/or index and match. Otherwise, you could do what's known as a full join

Comment: Google Sheets and Microsoft Excel have different feature sets and will most likely require a different answer each. The [google-sheets] tag description explicitly states _"Do NOT use with [excel]"_ and the [excel] tag description explicitly states _"Do NOT use with other spreadsheet software like [google-sheets]."_ Choose one platform and edit tags appropriately. To get help choosing a tool, try at [Software Recommendations Stack Exchange](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming your Google Sheets tabs are named `2017`, `2018`, `2019` and `2020`, choose **Insert > Sheet** and put this formula in cell `A1` of the new sheet:

```
=let( 
  stackValues_, lambda(sn,ra,reduce(tocol(ø,2),sn,lambda(rs,s,let(r,indirect(s&"!"&ra),l,max(index(row(r)*iferror(r<>""))),d,filter(r,row(r)<=l),if(counta(iferror(d)),vstack(rs,d),rs))))),

  query( 
    stackValues_({ "2017", "2018", "2019", "2020" }, "A2:D"), 
    "select Col1, Col2, Col3, count(Col1) 
     group by Col1, Col2, Col3 
     pivot Col4 
     label Col1 'id', Col2 'latitude', Col3 'longitude' ", 
    0 
  ) 
)
```

Sheet `2017`:

| id | latitude | longitude | year |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 15214537 | 14.4248605 | 50.0786082 | 2017 |
| 15214538 | 1.110626182 | 41.82943312 | 2017 |

Sheet `2018`:

| id | latitude | longitude | year |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 15214537 | 14.4248605 | 50.0786082 | 2018 |
| 15214539 | 7.323075285 | 35.85616867 | 2018 |

Results:

| id | latitude | longitude | 2017 | 2018 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 15214537 | 14.4248605 | 50.0786082 | 1 | 1 |
| 15214538 | 1.110626182 | 41.82943312 | 1 |  |
| 15214539 | 7.323075285 | 35.85616867 |  | 1 |

See [let()](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/13190535), [lambda()](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/12508718), [reduce()](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/12568597) and [query()](https://support.google.com/drive/answer/3093343).